# Splitting a paragraph into individual sentences. Am I covering all my bases here?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string with multiple sentences into a string array of individual sentences.

Here's what I have so far,

```
String input = "Hello World. " 
             + "Today in the U.S.A., it is a nice day! "
             + "Hurrah!"
             + "Here it comes... "
             + "Party time!";
String array[] = input.split("(?<=[.?!])\\s+(?=[\\D\\d])");
```

And this code is working perfectly fine. I get,

```
Hello World.
Today in the U.S.A., it is a nice day!
Hurrah!
Here it comes...
Party time!
```

I use the `lookbehind` functionality to see if a sentence ending punctuation mark precedes some or a single `white space(s)`. If so, we split.

But there are some exceptions that this regex doesn't cover. For example,
`The U.S. is a great country`, is incorrectly split as `The U.S.` and `is a great country`.

Any idea on how I can fix this?

And also, am I missing any edge cases here?

Comment: This is a pretty difficult problem, as you are encountering. Do you need to use regex, or are you open to other solutions? For example, Java includes a [BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/sentence.html) which works across locales.

Comment: You could try to catch cases where an ending punctuation mark is followed by one or more spaces and a _lower-case_ letter.  There will still be some edge cases.  "The U.S.S. Constitution is a great ship", for instance.  There will be no way to get this one right without major AI.

Comment: This is for a personal project. So, I'm not under any constraints. Would love to hear your solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't have to use a regular expression, you can make use of Java's built-in [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html).

The following code shows an example of parsing sentences, however BreakIterator supports other forms of parsing (word, line, etc.). You can also, optionally, pass in different locales if you are dealing with different languages. This example uses the default locale.

```
String input = "Hello World. " 
    + "Today in the U.S.A., it is a nice day! "
    + "Hurrah!"
    + "The U.S. is a great country. "
    + "Here it comes... "
    + "Party time!";
BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
iterator.setText(input);
int start = iterator.first();
for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
    System.out.println(input.substring(start, end));
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Hello World. 
Today in the U.S.A., it is a nice day! 
Hurrah!
The U.S. is a great country. 
Here it comes... 
Party time!
```